# Error while running make check for mesos-1.9.0 on Mac os

Tags: macos, mesos

While running `make check` for mesos-1.9.0 on mac os, I get an error for 'ulimit -u`. This is the error message on Terminal

```
Detected low process count ulimit (2837 vs 4096). Increase 'ulimit -u' to avoid spurious test failures.
```

I tried setting the hard and soft limits for ulimit (`ulimit -u 4096`and `ulimit -n 4096`) on the Terminal as well as updating my `.bash_profile` and running `source ~/.bash_profile` but `make check` still fails.

Can someone help me fix this ?

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo ulimit -n 65536 200000
```

Reference: https://wilsonmar.github.io/maximum-limits